# Allow container to read host network statistics, but bind to docker network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

tl; dr? Jump straight to **Question** ;)

### Context & Architecture

In this application designed with a micro-service architecture in mind, one can find notably two components:

- **`monitor`**: probes system metrics and report them via HTTP
- **`controller`**: read metrics reported by `monitor` and take actions according to rules defined in a configuration file.

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| host /                                               |
+-----/                                                |
|                                                      |
|   +-----------------+        +-------------------+   |
|   | monitor /       |        | controller /      |   |
|   +--------/        |        +-----------/       |   |
|   |  +----------+   |        |  +-------------+  |   |
|   |  | REST :80 |>--+--------+->| application |  |   |
|   |  +----------+   |        |  +-------------+  |   |
|   +-----------------+        +-------------------+   |
|                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

### Trouble with Docker

The only way I found for `monitor` to be able to read network statistics not contrived to its docker network stack was to start its container with `--network=host`. The following question assumes this is the only solution. If (fortunately) I were mistaken, please do answer with an alternative.

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  monitor:
    build: monitor
    network_mode: host
  controller:
    build: controller
    network_mode: host
```

### Question

Is there a way for `monitor` to serve its report on a docker network even though it reads statistics from the host network stack?

Or, is there a way for `controller` to *not* be on `--network=host` even though it connects to `monitor` which is?

*(note: I use docker-compose but a pure docker answer suits me)*

Comment: I don't think this is pertinent, but `monitor` is a python3+[flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) application. It reads OS metrics thanks to [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/).